# why CRLF transformed to LF when they are assigned to <input> using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

(1)A form include textarea,type text with line break into it.Like :

a
b

then submit the form and store the text to database.The length of contents is 4.I can output their ascii codes,using ord() function.They are **97(a)**, **13(cr)**, **10(lf)**, **98(b)**.

(2)Get the contents and assign them to the template using smarty.Like:

```
//$string is get from database.
$smarty->assign('str', $string);
```

Using an input element to store the contents in html template.

```
<input id="test" type="hidden" value="{$str}">
```

(3)Get the length of input value

```
document.getElementById("test").value.length;    //the result is 3
```

while using

```
{$str|@strlen}    //the result is 4
```

If I submit the form and get the ascii code of the cotents,they are  **97(a)**, **10(lf)**, **98(b)**. The character **13(cr)** is lost.

I googled a lot but didn't find the reason. Any explanation? Thanks a lot in advance.

---

I found this :

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188015

Someone replied in Comment 28 and official docs transferred to:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#preprocessing-the-input-stream

`"CR" (U+000D) characters and "LF" (U+000A) characters are treated specially. All CR characters must be converted to LF characters, and any LF characters that immediately follow a CR character must be ignored.`

Hope to help.

Comment: Why are you trying to store a multiline text into a single-line edit control?

Comment: @Cristik I investigated codes written before.The <input> is used as a medium and some other codes need to get the value by using this <input>.And from here, the length is wrong.

Comment: @AnoccLinn I think what @Cristik is saying is that if your data has multiple lines, you should use a `<textarea>` instead.

Comment: @T0xicCode Actually, `<textarea>` is used.But the implementation was set value of `<textarea>` by using the value of `<input>`.The value of `<input>` was wrong and so was that of `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that your html get's rendered like this (I've escaped the cr character:)

```
<input id="test" type="hidden" value="a\13
b">
```

and the browser trims the whitespace, thus deleting the CR character.

What you can do is to render urlencode($str) instead of the plain $str variable. This way the browser won't mess with your control characters. You'll have to urldecode on the other side, though.